# How to index more than 1000 documents in Elasticsearch with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I've built a Node.js application that is indexing result from an API as documents into Elasticsearch but ES will only index 1000 documents total. There are over 100k in total that need to be index. I can't seem to find anywhere that explains how to change this 1k document ingestion limit to a different number.

Here is a sample of my code, which other than the 1k document limit, works great.

```
ATX_TRAFFIC_INCIDENTS.data.map(async traffic => (
        await client.index({ 
            index: 'atx_traffic',
            id: traffic.traffic_report_id,
            type: 'data',
            body: {  
                traffic_report_id: traffic.traffic_report_id,
                published_date: traffic.published_date,
                issue_reported: traffic.issue_reported,
                status_date: traffic.traffic_report_status_date_time,
                status: traffic.traffic_report_status,
                address: traffic.address,
                latitude: traffic.latitude,
                longitude: traffic.longitude, 
                location:
                    { 
                        lat: traffic.latitude,
                        lon: traffic.longitude,
                    }
            }
        })
    ));
```

Comment: I really suggest you should use the [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_bulk) to index all your documents and not send them one at a time like you're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no intrinsic reason you cannot insert more than 1000 documents into ElasticSearch. Your issue is more than likely caused by mapping over your Promises, which is an anti-pattern.

By mapping Promises, you have no way to know if any of them resolve before your function completes. You also have no way of reacting to any errors thrown. You *really*, **really** should add a `.catch()` to each Promise, for the simple reason that you can be alerted to any failures.

The correct approach to running multiple Promises as a group is to store your Promises in an array which you pass to `Promise.all()`.

`Promise.all()` will wait until all your Promises have either resolved or rejected before returning control to your function.

Another plus when using `Promise.all()` is that once all of your Promises have resolved, it will return an array of all the results then return.

See [ES6 Promises: Patterns and Anti-Patterns](https://medium.com/datafire-io/es6-promises-patterns-and-anti-patterns-bbb21a5d0918) for more info.

Comment: The error seems to be with the API call itself as it is only returning 1000 results and not an error with elasticsearch indexing. I've added error handling with a try-catch block but all the same it seems to be a server side issue from the API